# Alternative for Modal in React Native Web

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-web

The lacking of Modal in React Native Web drove me to build a pop up component that is overlaid on top of the current view.

I have tried with the position 'absolute', top: 0 and left: 0 hack. That works well but it will not work properly if it is used in a children component, due to the auto zIndex by order of the component. The image below illustrates this issue (see the blue button is blocking the dropdown pop up):

[image]

Eventually I found out that React can render a component directly at the root (find out more at this [link](http://jamesknelson.com/rendering-react-components-to-the-document-body/)), which means the component will be rendered above other components, but this is for React but not React Native.

I wonder if there's something similar in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting up your Component at the last in hierarchy. And then use the position 'absolute', top: 0 and left: 0 hack. It should work.

For eg.

```
<View>
  {renderComponent1()}
  {renderComponent2()}
  {renderComponentWithAbsoluteStyling()} //Your component
</View>
```

In RN, lower component gets higher priority while rendering. So your component should override component1 and component2.

Comment: This wouldn't be great for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

use modal from 'react-native-paper', its worked for me